# I have defined a function in helper for saving data using model but it throws "__toString() must not throw an exception" error

Tags: laravel-5

I have defined a function in helper for saving data using model but it throws `"__toString()` must not throw an exception" error.

may be it is the problem of magic function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please share your exception backtrace

Comment: I have solved my problem, Actually Firstly i have defined a variable as string and then on same varible i have also defined an object, that's why that error occured.